# How to convert Logj4 logging level to JUL logging level?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to convert Log4j [`Level`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) to JUL [`Level`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html), and would like to use some out-of-the-box utility class. I've found [`UtilLoggingLevel`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/UtilLoggingLevel.html), but can't figure out how to use it for this particular case. Any ideas?

An ad hoc solution would be:

```
private static final ImmutableMap<Level, java.util.logging.Level> LEVELS =
    new ImmutableMap.Builder<Level, java.util.logging.Level>()
        .put(Level.ALL, java.util.logging.Level.ALL)
        .put(Level.DEBUG, java.util.logging.Level.FINE)
        .put(Level.ERROR, java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE)
        .put(Level.FATAL, java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE)
        .put(Level.INFO, java.util.logging.Level.INFO)
        .put(Level.OFF, java.util.logging.Level.OFF)
        .put(Level.TRACE, java.util.logging.Level.FINEST)
        .put(Level.WARN, java.util.logging.Level.WARNING)
        .build();
```

Would be nice to find a standardized function in log4j, if it exists...

Comment: I would suggest piping it through [`slf4j`](http://www.slf4j.org/); you can pipe the log4j logging in with log4j-over-slf4j and then pipe the logging out over JUL. Something like the "SLF4J bound to JUL..." diagram [here](http://www.slf4j.org/images/legacy.png).

Comment: In my case I just need to convert `Level` to `Level`, without sending an actual log message

Comment: to map between two "things", a Map (immutableMap in your case) is a good solution.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795373/how-to-map-levels-of-java-util-logging-and-slf4j-logger