# How to map levels of java.util.logging and SLF4J logger?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, java.util.logging

How do logging levels from java.util.logging map to SLF4J?

**SLF4J**

- trace
- debug
- info
- warn
- error
- fatal

**java.util.logging**

- finest
- finer
- fine
- config
- info
- warning
- severe

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the [SLF4JBridgeHandler](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) docs and testing (annotated with brackets):

```
[ALL    -> TRACE]
FINEST  -> TRACE
FINER   -> DEBUG
FINE    -> DEBUG
[CONFIG -> INFO]
INFO    -> INFO
WARNING -> WARN
SEVERE  -> ERROR
[OFF    -> ERROR]
```

Comment: also level ALL maps to TRACE and level OFF to ERROR