# Logback equivalent of log(Level, ... )function?

Tags: logging, logback, java.util.logging

I was surprised there's no generic log function for logback, in the same way as for java.util.logging. 
I have following legacy code using java.util.logging:

```
logger.log(logLevelOfChoice, "log message");
```

How to properly port it to logback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to map levels of java.util.logging and slf4j logger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795373/how-to-map-levels-of-java-util-logging-and-slf4j-logger)

Answer (score 1):

There is [no one method](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) that is equivalent.  You have to call each of the individual methods that map to the [right level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795373/how-to-map-levels-of-java-util-logging-and-slf4j-logger).